# AWS Cloud Trail Logs Parse

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

I want to parse the nested JSON from Cloud Trail logs to get the username Data and time how can I do it is there a code I can use in Lambda or there is some tool for example the JSON file looks like this

```
{"version":"0","id":"5bd0a964-0969-4b1a-badd-3b4f7e9e077f","detail-type":"AWS API Call via CloudTrail","source":"aws.ec2","account":"111111111","time":"2017-04-25T16:07:33Z","region":"us-west-2","resources":[],"detail":{"eventVersion":"1.05","userIdentity":{"type":"Root","principalId":"1111111","arn":"arn:aws:iam::137247507067:root","accountId":"111111111","accessKeyId":"AAAAAAAA","userName":"roger","sessionContext":{"attributes":{"mfaAuthenticated":"true","creationDate":"2017-04-25T05:44:56Z"}}},"eventTime":"2017-04-25T16:07:33Z","eventSource":"ec2.amazonaws.com","eventName":"ModifyImageAttribute","awsRegion":"us-west-2","sourceIPAddress":"X.X.X.X","userAgent":"console.ec2.amazonaws.com","requestParameters":{"imageId":"ami-36e85556","launchPermission":{"add":{"items":[{"userId":"879125893843"}]}},"attributeType":"launchPermission"},"responseElements":{"_return":true},"requestID":"06ae4745-2d29-4a3b-b526-c5d8c4b4a7fc","eventID":"fc57b805-ae30-4ec7-bf4f-7a9c971ae0c7","eventType":"AwsApiCall"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS Athena.

It basically loads the cloudtrail logs into a table, so we can easily query all the things.

It has more option to analyze the cloudtrail logs.For example, if you want to know who launched the ec2 instance, then query  like this,

```
SELECT date_format(from_iso8601_timestamp(eventTime), '%Y-%m-%d') AS EventDate,useridentity.arn UserARN,
       awsregion AS Region,
       json_extract_scalar(item,'$.instanceId') AS InstanceId
FROM cloudtrail_logs
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (cast(json_extract(responseElements,'$.instancesSet.items') AS array(json))) AS i (item)
WHERE eventsource='ec2.amazonaws.com'
  AND eventname = 'RunInstances'
  AND eventtime >= '2017-04-25T02:00:00.000'
 order by eventtime desc limit 2;
```

The result is,
[image]

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/aws-cloudtrail-and-amazon-athena-dive-deep-to-analyze-security-compliance-and-operational-activity/